# C++ compiling Issue

Tags: c++

I have been having an issue with an error that has been given to me when I try to compile. The error says, `error: no matching function for call to 'Invoice::Invoice(const char [10], double, int)'`
It is giving me the error on

```
//create an invoice using constructor with parameters
    Invoice ductTape("Duct Tape",2.99,10);
```

Here is my code, first one you will need to save it as Invoice.h It has taken me a while to actually fix most of the errors. Only, this one is the only error I am having.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Invoice
    {

    public:

        void setDescription(string bagofhammers)
        {
    description = "bag of hammers";
        }

        void setQuantity(int)
        {
            quantity = 1;
        }
        void setPrice (int)
        {
            price = 12.99;
        }

        void ductTape()
        {
            setDescription("Duct Tape");
            setPrice(2.99);
            setQuantity(10);
        }
        string getDescription(string description)
        {
            return description;
        }

        int getQuantity(int quantity)
        {
            return quantity;
        }

        int getPrice(double price)
        {
            return price;
        }

        void print() 
        { 
            std::cout << "Invoiced item is: " << getDescription(description) << endl;

            std::cout << "Quantity ordered: "<< getQuantity(quantity) << endl;

            std::cout << "Each unit's price is: "<< getPrice(price) << endl;

            std::cout << "Total Amount: "<< (getPrice(price)*getQuantity(quantity)) << endl;
        }


    private:
        string description;
        double price;
        int quantity;
    };
```

And this one is the program that will use it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Invoice.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string description;
    double price;
    int quantity;

    cout << "Enter the description: ";
    getline(cin, description);

    cout << "Enter the unit price: ";
    cin >> price;

    cout << "Enter the quantity: ";
    cin >> quantity;
    cout << endl;//a new line

    //create an invoice using default constructor
    Invoice hammers;
    hammers.setDescription(description);
    hammers.setPrice(price);
    hammers.setQuantity(quantity);

    //now print the invoice
    hammers.print();
    cout << endl;

    //create an invoice using constructor with parameters
    Invoice ductTape("Duct Tape",2.99,10);

    cout << "[Invoice for object created using constructor]" <<endl;
    ductTape.print();
    cin.ignore(255,'\n');//ignore any leftover new lines
    cin.get();//pause the output...
    return 0;
}
```

I would assume that I screwed something up on the ductTape part. You must keep in mind, this is the first time I'm taking C++. So if you don't mind explaining what is wrong with this, hopefully I can learn from it.

Comment: Where's the constructor that takes parameters? You don't have one.

Comment: Is this a follow up from a previous post?

Comment: @Ed: [It's a repost.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513261/c-issue-with-program-not-compiling)

Comment: @Billy: WTF are you doing? Do not replace the contents of your question with "it works! it works! it works!" please.

Comment: This should be tagged `homework`

Comment: Please do NOT remove your original text in the future. If an answer here helped you, accept that answer. What use is 'it works' to future visitors?

Answer (score 7):

You're missing constructors. Add to the public section in header

```
Invoice() :
description(0), price(0), quantity(0) {}

Invoice(const char* _description, double _price, int _quantity) :
description(_description), price(_price), quantity(_quantity) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message is pretty clear. You need a constructor for your `Invoice` class.

```
Invoice::Invoice(const char* description_, double price_, int quantity_)
 : description(description_), price(price_), quantity(quantity_)
{}
```

This constructor makes use of initialization list to initialize member variables with constructor arguments.

EDIT: As @the.malkolm pointed you're also making use of `Invoice`'s default constructor in your code by defining `Invoice hammers;`

Since you implemented a constructor which takes arugments, you now need need to implement the default constructor as well.

```
Invoice::Invoice()
  : description(0), price(0), quantity(0)
{}
```

Comment: Yeah, but don't forget about non-argument one. The author uses this too.

Comment: yeah well whatever :) his whole `Invoice` class is pretty much flawed with its `ductTape()` member function... I mean I don't even know where to start an explanation, that's the role of some introduction to C++ book

Comment: @Tomalak at first I wrote it without underscores then thought it would look less confusing to a C++ newcomer to have a distinction between argument name and member name...

Comment: You understand. I understand. What about author who is asking this kind of question? Are you sure he will understand?

Comment: @Gregory: Why? The two values are the same! :D

Comment: @the.malkolm: It is counter-productive to try to second guess what the OP will and will not understand. If there is something in an answer that they do not understand, then that's what _comments_ are for: seeking clarification. That and a good C++ book. There is **no** good reason to write worse-quality code just on the assumption that the sensible code will remain a mystery to the OP for all time.

Comment: So adding that underscore makes the code worse now? :D Please no bikeshed discussion

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the correct constructor in your `Invoice` class.

Comment: `ductTape` takes no parameters either.

Answer (score 1):

You have not written the constructors

```
ie. Invoice() { ....} and Invoice(const char * a, double b, int c) {....}
```